# UPDATE Database Redirecting to Other Page

Tags: php, sql-update

I am having trouble with my "update.php" file, instead of going to my "update page" my button brings me to the header location which is "index.php"
This is my update.php file:

```
  <?php
    require 'database.php';
    $id = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['ID'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['ID'];
        }
    if (null==$id){
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }
    if (!empty($_POST)){
        $codeError = null;

        //post values
        $code = $_POST['codeVal'];
        //validate input

        $valid = true;
        if (empty($code)){
            $codeError = 'Please Enter Code';
            $valid = false;
        }

            // update data
        if ($valid){
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE production SET CODE = ? WHERE ID = ?";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($code,$id));
            Database::disconnect();
            header('location:../index.php');
            }
    }else{
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM production WHERE ID = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $code = $data['CODE'];
        Database::disconnect();
        }
?>
```

While my other page is this one. This is my report.php file

```
 <?php
          include 'database.php';
          $pdo = Database::connect();
          $sql = 'SELECT * FROM production ORDER BY ID DESC';
          foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="13%">'. $row['CODE'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td style="text-align:center" width=18%>';
                  echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="update.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">Update</a>';
                  echo ' ';
                  echo '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="delete.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">Delete</a>';
                  echo '</td>';                    
                  echo '</tr>';
                       }
  Database::disconnect();
  ?>
```

So when I press the **UPDATE** button on my report.php file, I was expecting to head to update.php file, but that's not what's happening, instead, I am redirected to my index.php file. What am I supposed to do?

And this one is my form on my update.php file

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label for="codeVal" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="text-align:right">Order Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text"  id="codeVal" name="codeVal" class="form-control input-sm"style="text-align:center" value="
            <?php echo !empty($code)?$code:'';?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try changing `if (null==$id){
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }` to `if (empty($id)){
        header("Location:../index.php");
    }`

Comment: Problem is here `if($valid)` this runs and in there your have redirect to index.php. Remove that line and it will just load in to update.php and stay there.

Comment: You are learning I know, but once you find your issue here, look at your code security before you continue. $_GET is not safe. instead  look at using  filtering its safer for your application/data/security filter_input()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$id` is and remains `null`:

```
$id = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['ID'])) {
   $id = $_REQUEST['ID'];
}
```

You build you links like this:

```
 echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="update.php?id='.$row['ID'].'">Update</a>';
                                                          ^^ here
```

So the value in `$_GET` will be `$_GET['id']` and not `$_GET['ID']`.